# How to select drop-down value from CSV file using Apache POI - Selenium Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I am currently working on a web form (Selenium Automation) where I need to display values from a CSV file in a drop-down input text field. I've managed to read the CSV data using Apache POI and successfully displayed the results in the console. Additionally, I've been able to populate a regular input text field with values from the CSV.

However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to populate a drop-down input field with these values. Unlike a regular input field where SendKeys works, it seems that the same method doesn't work for drop-down fields (as it is a non-editable/ readable input field).

Is there a recommended approach or a workaround to populate a drop-down input field with values from a CSV file? The CSV file has a specific column that corresponds to the drop-down field.

Here is my script:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "test1data")
    public void test1(String name, String country, String city, String age, String acctype) throws Exception {
// getting values from csv file using Apache POI 
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Country: " + country);
        System.out.println("City: " + city);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age);
        System.out.println("Account Type: " + acctype);
//      try {
//          Thread.sleep(5000);
//      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement nameinp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/app-main-layout/div/div/div/app-stocks/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/symbol-dialog/div[1]/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div[3]/input"));
        
        nameinp.sendKeys(Symbol);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//here country and city are drop-down fields, currently I am trying to get country values from CSV
        WebElement countryinp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/app-main-layout/div/div/div/app-stocks/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/mat-form-field[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/mat-select/div/div[1]"));
        countryinp.click(); // It opens drop-down list

    }
```

I have attempted a couple of approaches to populate the drop-down input field with values from the CSV file, but unfortunately, none of them seem to work as intended. The approaches I've tried include Javascript executor and sendKeys.

The variable 'country' holds the value fetched from the CSV file, but despite the attempts to set this value in the drop-down field, the field remains empty (it just opens the drop-down list but nothing is shown in drop-down input field).

My goal here is to successfully display the values fetched from the CSV file in the drop-down input field. This is part of a data-driven approach I'm implementing to thoroughly test the form with various inputs.

Comment: To clarify: you are reading the value from your CSV file, and you wish to set the drop-down to the value you have read? Also, is the drop-down a standard HTML select element, or is it created by the javascript framework the application is using? Please update your question with this information.